# JUnit/TestNg: How to simplify/combine multiple { try fail() catch } for same exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

Example (`<Expected Exception>` for `assert 1` & `assert 2` is same) :

```
@junit.framework.Test // or @org.testng.annotations.Test
public void testCase() {
    try {
        // assert 1
        fail();
    } catch (<Expected Exception>) {

    }

    try {
        // assert 2
        fail();
    } catch (<Expected Exception>) {

    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your intent correctly—each block within the `try {...} catch` should throw `ExpectedException` (otherwise, that's a test failure). Is it too hard to break up this test into multiple methods, and each annotated with `@Test(expected=ExpectedException.class)`?

Comment: @Cedric & AlistairIsrael : Thanks for the answers. But I'm hope there is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're feeling adventurous, you can also try out assertThrows:

https://github.com/dsaff/junit.contrib

Feel free to ask if you have any problems.

Comment: Great! Thank for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If it's too hard to break this up into individual test methods, here's what's worked for me in the past.

Create a method `expectsException()` that expects a `Callback`.

```
interface Callback {
    void call() throws Exception;
}

void expectsException(Callback callback) {
    try {
        callback.call();
        fail("ExpectedException was not thrown!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!(e instanceof ExpectedException)) {
            fail("Expecting ExpectedException, got " + e.getClass());
        }
        assertEquals("Expected exception message", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then, wrap up the code inside your `try {...} catch` blocks in the `Callback`:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    expectsException(new Callback() {
        public void call() throws Exception {
            // assert 1
        }
    });

    expectsException(new Callback() {
        public void call() throws Exception {
            // assert 2
        }
    });
}
```

Note however, that depending on what you're doing in the `catch` block, this may or may not end up less verbose than a straightforward `try {...} catch`.

(When Java gets proper closures, then this approach will make a lot more sense.)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably break your method into two separate methods that will each throw:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = NullPointerException.class)
public void testCase1() {
  // assert 1
}


@Test(expectedExceptions = NullPointerException.class)
public void testCase2() {
  // assert 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) might help:

```
public void testCase() {
    // assert 1
    verifyException(obj, MyException.class).do(1);
    // assert 2
    verifyException(obj, MyException.class).do(2);
}
```